# Getting error while using “FilterExecutingContext” , How to use ‘OnActionExecuting’ method of ActionFilterAttribute class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want implement HTML compression in my project using below code.

```
public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute {

public override void OnActionExecuting(FilterExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

    string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

    acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

    HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

    if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
        response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
    }
    else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
        response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
    }
}
}
```

But, i got an error on `FilterExecutingContext`. It shows error like `code not found...` 
So please give me suggestion how i should implement HTML compression in my project.
And any other suggestion please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method signature of `OnActionExecuting` has been changed to:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

Replace `FilterExecutingContext` with `ActionExecutingContext`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Add verification for Accept encoding. you have used incorrect letter case for

> Accept-encoding, GZIP and DEFLATE

. Please Sample code below:

```
 if(Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"] != null &&
     Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"].Contains("gzip")) {
       Response.Filter = new GZipStream(Response.Filter, 
                         CompressionMode.Compress, true);
       Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
  }
  else if(Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"] != null &&
          Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"].Contains("deflate")) {
      Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(Response.Filter, 
                        CompressionMode.Compress, true);
      Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
  }
```

Courtsy http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14761/HTTP-Compression-A-Quick-and-Dirty-Solution